# Accepting a 2-D array (int type) from a function and returning it to the main function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I just wanna take size of the 2-D array as arguments in the function, accept the array and somehow put it in the main function for further tasks.
I tried watching some videos and posts but did not get my answer.
Please help and take me out of this problem as always.

```
int *accept(int a,int b)
{
   int x[50][50];
 for(int i=0;i<a;++i)
 {
  cout<<"Enter elements for "<<i+1<<" th row";
   for(int j=0;j<b;++j)
   {
    cout<<"Enter "<<j+i<<" th element \n";
    cin>>x[i][j];
   }
 }
 return *x;
 }

 void main()
 {
 int arr[50][50],m,n;
 cout<<"Enter the no of rows you want : ";
 cin>>m;
 cout<<"Enter the no of columns you want : ";
 cin>>n;
 arr[50][50]=accept(m,n); //how to copy?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `memcpy()`,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void accept(void* arr, int a, int b)
{
     int x[a][b];

     for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
     {
        cout << "Enter elements for " << i+1 << " th row";

        for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j)
        {
            cout << "Enter " << j+i << " th element \n";
            cin >> x[i][j];
        }
     }

     memcpy(arr, x, sizeof(int) * a * b);
 }

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    cout << "Enter the no of rows you want : ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter the no of columns you want : ";
    cin >> n;

    int arr[m][n];
    accept(&arr, m, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can find info about this function here: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/